# How can we compare biases of two estimators with no parametric form?

Tags: inference, nonparametric, bias, estimators

I was reading in my textbook that the bias of a statistical estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ can be quantified as $B(\hat{\theta}_n,\theta)=E[\hat{\theta}_n-\theta]$. This expectation seems to be w.r.t. to the sampling distribution of the estimator for samples of fixed size $n$ (please correct me if I'm mistaken).

So I was wondering if we had two estimators $\hat{\theta}_n^1$ and $\hat{\theta}_n^2$ whose biases decrease with sample size $n$, how would we compare them. For example, if the bias of $\hat{\theta}_n^1$ starts out smaller than that of $\hat{\theta}_n^2$ until $n=100$, but after that reduces much slower than that of $\hat{\theta}_n^2$, how can we compare the two? Can we say that $\hat{\theta}_n^1$ is more biased than $\hat{\theta}_n^2$ because $\hat{\theta}_n^1=O(\hat{\theta}_n^2)$? How does this apply to machine learning where we use generic statements such as "linear models have higher bias than neural networks"? [image: models]

Comment: I like this question but am confused by the title. What does your question have to do with lacking a parametric form? (And what do you even mean by a parametric form?)

Comment: I would use the size of my sample for the comparison.  For applying an estimator to a sample, I could care less about any other sample size.  This question could become germane for power analysis or sample design, but it doesn't present any conceptual difficulty.  After all, if you are comparing estimators solely on bias, then use the one with smaller bias, whichever it might be.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Apologies for the late reply, I must have missed the notifications in my inbox. I guess my question was more about generic statements, particularly in the case of machine learning (e.g. decision trees of depth 1 have more bias than decision trees of depth 5). I wondered how such generalizations are made mathematically, especially when there is no closed-form equation for quantifying the bias (that is what I meant by 'nonparametric').